# Filter dataframe for value that exists in all dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PortDt': ['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-03-31'],
    'loannum': ['111', '111', '222', '111', '333']
})
```

I want to filter the dataset so that I am left with only records who appear in every distinct value for `PortDt`.

For this example, the result would be:

```
PortDt     |   loannum
-----------+-------------
2022-01-31 |  111
2022-02-28 |  111
2022-03-31 |  111
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with 'nunique' and comparing to the overall number of unique values:

```
out = df[df.groupby('loannum')['PortDt']
           .transform('nunique').eq(df['PortDt'].nunique())]
```

Or same logic with better efficiency:

```
s = df.groupby('loannum')['PortDt'].nunique().eq(df['PortDt'].nunique())

df[df['loannum'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Or with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)+[`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) instead of `groupby`:

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['PortDt'], df['loannum']).all()
out = df[df['loannum'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Output:

```
       PortDt loannum
0  2022-01-31     111
1  2022-02-28     111
3  2022-03-31     111
```

Comment: Why not just `df.drop_duplicates("PortDt")`?

Comment: You could also use another `nunique` instead of `len()` and `unique()` :)

Comment: @TheMaster - What if the first row was the one containing `loannum` 222?

Comment: @not_speshal yes very true ^^ Thanks!

Comment: @TheMaster because this is not the expected logic, In fact several groups could match the requirement and you'd have duplicates.

Comment: @not_speshal and mozway Thanks. Understood.